# how to delete/replace parts of a string in mysql using wildcards?

Tags: mysql

I have thousands of strings in a MySQL table like

```
some-text-for-read/id123456
some-other-text-to-read-too/id456789
```

I want to make them

```
/id123456
/id456789
```

How can i do it using wildcards for the text part?
I tried everything I found like
"REPLACE %id%"
kind of queries, but nothing worked, because I didn't do it right probably.

Comment: The part to delete always precedes the first `/`?

Comment: Yes, it's always like this, but there are special characters in the text before the "/"

Comment: It does not matter what precedes it as long as you consistently want to remove up to the first `/`.

Comment: Yes, I just want to keep the "/id123456" part. The "/" is always the first character I want to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
UPDATE your_table set your_field = CONCAT('/', SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_field, '/', -1))
```

Answer (score 4):

Using a combination of the [MySQL string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) `LOCATE()` and `SUBSTR()`, you use `LOCATE()` to find the position in the string of the first `/` character, and `SUBSTR()` to return the substring *beginning with* that position in the original string.

You can place all of it into an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_column = SUBSTR(your_column, LOCATE('/', your_column))
-- Only on rows where the / is present, if there are non-matching rows
-- LOCATE() returns 0 when the string isn't found
WHERE LOCATE('/', your_column) > 0
```

Example:

```
> SELECT SUBSTR('some-other-text-to-read-too/id456789', LOCATE('/', 'some-other-text-to-read-too/id456789')) AS val;
+-----------+
| val       |
+-----------+
| /id456789 |
+-----------+
```

And the reason you need the `WHERE` clause -- everything will be deleted if there is no `/` in the row:

```
/* This has no '/' */
> SELECT SUBSTR('some-other-text-to-read-tooid456789', LOCATE('/', 'some-other-text-to-read-tooid456789')) AS val;
+-----+
| val |
+-----+
|     |
+-----+
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') WHERE LOCATE('/' my_column) > 0' at line 2

Comment: @Hunnenkoenig Missing `,` between the args.  `LOCATE('/', my_column)`

Comment: There is ALWAYS a "/" in the row.

Comment: If that is guaranteed, then feel free to leave off the `WHERE` clause. But for future readers of this question, I'll leave it in.

Comment: Now I get an ERROR at "for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2" I added the missing ","

Comment: @Hunnenkoenig Sorry :-/ Missing the 1st arg to `SUBSTR()`, as in `SUBSTR(your_column, LOCATE('/', your_column))`  -- it's difficult to get it all correct without having setup the whole thing in sqlfiddle.com